# Accidentally flagged old post

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, old-questions

So there was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363938/asp-net-html-editor-what-would-you-choose) that popped up in my feed.  Despite having an accepted answer, I believe the question really is opinion based (of course that is just my opinion :) ).  It was only as I flagged it as such that I noticed that it was from 2010.

I'm not sure why it was randomly edited today, but my flag is probably a little redundant.  Is there any way to remove my flag?  Should I worry?  My first instinct on the question is still valid, so even if it's four years old I don't believe it really is a question that can have a definitive answer.

What to do?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You made the right choice!

Even though a question is really old, doesn't mean it's immune from being closed.

The question is now closed.

---

If a question on the site, **any question**, no matter its age, is off-topic or otherwise appropriate to being closed for the current close-reasons/flag-reasons that are available at this current point in time, then you should do it!

Comment: If the question had been a new one that popped up into my feed, I wouldn't have any concerns about flagging it.  But given it had an accepted answer and seemed to have survived for four years, it gave me pause :)

Comment: I notice that the question is now gone, I'm assuming because of its age (older than 30 days?) that once flagged it was automatically removed in a daily batch job...?  Or did a mod manually remove it?

Comment: @JaneS The question was manually flagged for deletion by moderators (that is, users with at least 10k reputation, not diamond moderators).

Comment: @duskwuff Thanks for clarifying :)  Obviously at my rep level all I can see is a deleted post stating that the post had been removed for moderation purposes.